# not able to download maven dependencies in spring tool

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

Here is my `pom.xml` file, when i am importing the project,  its is showing error on the top line in pom.xml file as "failure to transfer xstream because its cached in the local directory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced"

I am totally new to this please help me out.

I was learning through a tutorial Spring with JPA and Hibernate, but i am stuck with this please help me out, and thanks in advance

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.pluralsight</groupId>
  <artifactId>FitnessTracker</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>FitnessTracker Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>FitnessTracker</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail about the error you're seeing.

Comment: And what is your error?

Comment: Also, if you're new to this, you shouldn't use such old versions of everything. Spring 4.x is out for a long time, JUnit 4 even more, Jackson 2 and servlet 3 as well.

Comment: I did that, now only one dependencies is not able to download, that is" jstl " which is version 1.2 , thanks for ur time, please help me with this dependencies

Comment: When i did "mvn dependency:purge-local-repository", my jstl dependencies is downloaded, but i am getting error at the top line of the pom.xml, that failure  to transfer xstream because its cached in the local directory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -U parameter while building your project.

```
mvn clean install -U
```

If it does not work delete xstream's folder from your local maven repo and do

```
 mvn clean install -U
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, i already did that but the error in the pom.xml is not going

Comment: can you delete xstream's folder and its content from your local maven repo and do a clean install again?

Comment: thanks a lot sezin, by deleting xtream and updating my maven project it worked

Comment: happy to help @ratnesh. updated my answer so people can see it more easily